# Can I use an existing content database for a new web application?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

If I use an existing web application's content database for a new web application, Will that import all lists,sites and libraries into the new web application being created ?

Or

The normal backup and restore is required ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A content database contains one or more site collections and all the websites, documents etc inside that database.

This means you can take a copy of a content database from your production environment and use it in your dev environment. However you will not be able to attach two copies of the same content database to a web application.

It may be possible to use it again for a second web application on the same SharePoint farm, but I strongly recommend against doing that in a production environment.

A content database does not store custom code and other customisations, these have to be installed before the restored sites will work correctly.

For more:
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2010/11/02/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-migrate-a-sharepoint-2007-site-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: "It may be possible to use it again for a second web application on the same SharePoint farm" - I made a backup of existing content database, restored it to a new one on sql server, and attached it to a new web application on the same farm with stsadm addcontentdb, but when I browse to the new web application I get HTTP 404 error. And when I look inside the ContentDatabases in Central Admin, it shows 0 sites.